# Unable to get Urdu data from database in my dotnet core 6 using PdfSharpCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fonts, pdfsharpcore

I am trying to get a Pdf Form with the specific user data, like name, age, dob, registration number, etc, The data stored in English or Dates are fine how ever name and address are in urdu which is shown as rectangle boxes

My Backend Code:

```
using PdfSharpCore;
using PdfSharpCore.Pdf;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;
using PdfSharpCore.Fonts;
using PdfSharpCore.Utils;
using PdfSharpCore.Drawing;

    [HttpGet("{serialNo}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateNotificationsPdfForm(string serialNo)
    {
        Notifications notification = await repository.GetNotificationReport(serialNo); 
        JsonElement json = notification.Params.RootElement;
        Member member = await memberRepository.Get(json.GetProperty("MemberId").GetInt32());

        NotificationPdfModel data = new()
        {
            FullName = member.FullName,
            RegistranNumber = member.RegistrationNumbers.Where(r => r.Current).Select(s => s.Code).FirstOrDefault(),
            FatherName = member.FatherName,
            Dob = member.DateOfBirth,
            Education = member.MemberEducations.Select(s => s.SetupEducations.Degree).FirstOrDefault(),
            Occupation = member.MemberOccupations.Select(s => s.SetupOccupations.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
            MaritalStatus = member.MemberMaritalStatuses.Select(s => s.SetupMaritalStatus.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
            ContactNo = string.Join(",", memberRepository.GetMemberMobileNumbers(member)),
            PreviousAddress = memberRepository.GetMemberCurrentAddress(member),
            ResponsibilityName = member.MemberResponsibilities.Where(mr => mr.Current).Select(s => s.DisplayName).FirstOrDefault(),
            MubtadiCourse = member.CourseParticipants.Where(cp => cp.Course.Published && cp.Course.CourseType.StaticType == CourseType.StaticCourseTypes.MubtadiTarbiyatiCourse).Select(cp => new MemberCourseModel(){
                StartDate = cp.Course.StartDate,
                Location = cp.Course?.Address ?? cp.Course?.CourseLocation?.Address,
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
            MultazimCourse = member.CourseParticipants.Where(cp => cp.Course.Published && cp.Course.CourseType.StaticType == CourseType.StaticCourseTypes.MultazimTarbiyatiCourse).Select(cp => new MemberCourseModel(){
                StartDate = cp.Course.StartDate,
                Location = cp.Course?.Address ?? cp.Course?.CourseLocation?.Address,
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
            NisabBaraEMutaliya = json.GetProperty("NisabBaraEMutaliya").GetString(),
            TaluqMaAllah = json.GetProperty("TaluqMaAllah").GetString(),
            SamaOTaat = json.GetProperty("SamaOTaat").GetString(),
            SamaOBasar = json.GetProperty("SamaOBasar").GetString(),
            InfradiDawat = json.GetProperty("InfradiDawat").GetString(),
            JihadBilMaal = json.GetProperty("JihadBilMaal").GetString(),
        };

        var document = new PdfDocument();
        string HtmlContent = "<h1>"+data.Dob.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+"</h1>";
        HtmlContent += "<h1 style='font-family: Alvi Nastaleeq;'>"+data.FullName+"</h1>";
        PdfGenerator.AddPdfPages(document, HtmlContent, PageSize.A4);

        byte[] response = null;
        
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.Save(ms);
            response = ms.ToArray();
        }

        string FileName = "Test.pdf";

        return File(response, "application/pdf", FileName);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the correct language character set installed?

Comment: Are you sure the data is stored in the DB correctly?

Comment: Data is coming from the database, I can see it in console and When I generate the form with dates and data in english it prints it fine on an A4 size page as pdf but when I use urdu data which I can see in Console (front end), it show as boxes like we see in a computer when it shows an unknown language @Charlieface

Comment: In Console, it shows all the data fine (urdu and english) but it shows english data fine in pdf but not the urdu one @ChrisBD

Comment: Maybe you need to change font?

Comment: How can I do that? Following are the fonts it shows in my console when i send the req, 2 of them are of Urdu:

Fonts:
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/Alvi-Nastaleeq-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/MehrNastaliqWebRegular.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
@Charlieface

Comment: What are you using to view your pdf document with? If you are using Adobe Acrobat you may need to add Urdu language support.https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/kb/change-language-settings-of-acrobat.html

Comment: I am able to get the urdu data but it is showing it from left to right instead of right to left